# HTML: child node know which child it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Does a child node know which child it is?

Can jQuery determine this? I'm using the nth-child and nth-of-type CSS selector heavily on this project. I suspect using `this` would help.

For instance, how would a function event handler look where:

upon user click on the 5th child image of a div -> alert(5).

Comment: You can try `$(this).index()`

Comment: I believe the wording on my question is intuitive and helpful for people to search for; but hey stackoverflow is saturated as it is.

Comment: No, it's not intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `index()` function to find an element's position within a set of elements. Something like this:

```
$('div img').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).closest('div').find('img').index(this);
    alert(idx);
});
```

This is similar to using `.index()` without any parameters, but it's more general-purpose, as it looks at the selected set, rather than just the immediate siblings - which may not be images.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).parent().find("img").index($(this)));
```

...should do it. It's zero-based.